# I am trying to put results from JSON into an NSArray

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json

I am trying to pull results from a JSON query and place those results into a NSArray so that I can list the results in a TableView.

This is my switch statement in PHP:

```
switch ($_POST['command']) {

    case "account":
        account($_SESSION['IdUser']);break;     

}
```

And then, in my api.php file, I have the following function that allows me to query that database to extract all accounts where the account owner is the 'logged in / session' user.

```
function account($IdUser) {
    $login = query("SELECT IdUser, name FROM account WHERE IdUser='%d'", $IdUser);
}
```

Here is my code for getting those values from the query.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"account", @"command", nil];
    [[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:params onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        NSArray* res = [json objectForKey:@"result"];

    }];
```

I then create the Tableview methods...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [res count];
}
```

And then...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [res objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

When I run my iOS Simulator, I am getting no values in my table.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: What's `res`? Shouldn't be `recipes`instead in `tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath:`? Now what's your exact issue? Any error message?

Comment: Definitely need a lot more information here. @Larme is right- what is being held in `res` and why is the number of rows based on `recipes` instead? What is your original JSON dictionary that's being returned? What problems are you having with your current code that isn't working?

Comment: I will update my question. My apologies.

Comment: try reload the table after array is updated

Comment: What is the "API" class?  I don't recognize that name.  What does your original JSON look like?

Comment: I'm thinking the NSArray object is not correct. How do I do that @NeverBe.

Answer (score 0):

For first add a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *res;
```

then you can

```
    NSMutableDictionary* params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      @"account", @"command", nil];
     [[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:params onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
     self.res = [json objectForKey:@"result"];
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
        }];

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [self.res count];
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }
NSDictionary *user = [self.res objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [user objectForKey:@"name"];
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: I have just made the modifications you have mentioned and this line [self.tableView reload]; is telling me that property tableView is not found on object type "AccountViewController".

Comment: you should link your control to this outlet on storyboard

Comment: I have linked the Table View control (datasource, delegate) to the storyboard.

Comment: how looks your json? do you sure that uou got it correctly?

Comment: I am using the same formatted JSON when displaying the session user's name.

Comment: Do you have email? I can send you my .m and .h files

Comment: i have, but i can't show it here. upload your project to the ftp or other file storage.